# PHP Mail Headers Problem

Tags: php

I'm creating a simple PHP mail function. I have a small problem with its header. I'm trying to set the senders name to be the clients website, and when I use the following code:

```
$headers = "From: Websites' Name";
$headers .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n"."Content-Type:  multipart/mixed;\n"." boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\"";
$headers .= "Reply-To:  $email <$email>\n";
$headers .= "X-Sender:  $email <$email>\n";
$headers .= "X-Priority: 1\n";
```

I receive the E-mail and the sender would be "Websites' Name@h184905.safesecureweb.com". What I want is, to get rid of the "@h184905.safesecureweb.com" I only want the "Websites' Name" to appear ... Can anyone help me with that ???

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible. An E-Mail needs a valid `from` address.

The best you can do is what you already do in the other headers:

```
$headers = "From: \"Websites' Name\" <email@example.com>";
```

(insert your valid E-Mail [must be on the same server] for the example address)

I am assuming the `Websites'` is an example only - you may need to escape the quote character otherwise.

Comment: That will send a mail saying `From: Websites' <Name@h184905.safesecureweb.com>`; the displayed name must be quoted if it contains spaces; the mailer takes the first non-quoted (and non-encoded, in case of QP or base64) space to be the separator between display name and e-mail address.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set a valid `From` header - that is, a valid e-mail address. You can do this:

```
From: "Websites' Displayed Name" <some@address.example.com>
```

Note that if you have a space in the displayed name, you need to enclose it in double quotes, (and for non-ASCII characters (e.g. "ščřž"), you'll need to use quoted-pritable or base64).

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned, you need to provide a valid mailbox in the `From` field. You can use [`imap_rfc822_write_address`](http://php.net/imap_rfc822_write_address) for that:

```
$headers = array(
    "From: ".imap_rfc822_write_address("info", "example.com", "Website's Name"),
    "MIME-Version: 1.0",
    "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\"",
    "Reply-To: ".imap_rfc822_write_address("info", "example.com", "Website's Name"),
    "X-Sender: ".imap_rfc822_write_address("info", "example.com", "Website's Name"),
    "X-Priority: 1"
);
$headers = implode("\r\n", $headers);
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe take a look at the mail() function at php.net

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php